# how to migrate from non encrypted to encrypted realm schema in android

Tags: android, encryption, realm, migrate

I want to migrate from non-encrypted to encrypted Realm in android. How can it be implemented?

e.g. from

```
 RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                .Builder()
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

to

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                    .Builder()
                    .schemaVersion(1)
                    .encryptionKey(some64ByteKey())
                    .migration(new Migration())
                    .build();
            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Comment: `writeEncryptedCopyTo()` might help

Comment: i got it working using writeEncryptedCopyTo thanks. Though i needed to check if the encrypted config already exists